# in grails create for the currently looged in user

Tags: grails

I have a User domain and a Child domain in the User domain I have:

```
 static hasMany = [children:Child]
```

and I want to create an instance of the Child domain for the currently logged in user
In the user controller I have:

```
     def createChild() {
    [userInstance: new Child(params)]

}
```

This does not work. I have been working on this all morining can some one please help as I am at a dead end.
FYI i am using spring security core

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def child = new Child(params)
if (child.validate())
    userInstance.addToChildren(child)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Im not sure where I should put this. would this be in the Child controller under create?

Comment: Yes, if logged in user can add children.